# Why client gets 403 error on successful request - Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm playing with Spring Boot and I've got to the point where I'm trying to manage security. I was following outdated tutorial, so there was a lot I had to improve myself, but I've got to the point where my requests work fine - require previous login and then CSRF token in the header and they do whet they are suppose to do logging statuses like 200/201, but also 400/404 (all custom). The problem is that I know about it only if I read the logs (or verify the result by for example checking if something was created/deleted), because the response I receive is usually 403. I say usually, because I somehow managed to fix POST->201 when I was fixing something else (so I don't even know how).

Here's my config:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler delegate = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        delegate.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
        CsrfTokenRequestHandler requestHandler = delegate::handle;
        http.cors().and().csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/login").csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
            .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/sayhello").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
                    .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        return http.build();
    }
```

Example of "failing" request:

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'http://<xxx>/api/todo/40ae6186' \
--header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: <xxx>' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=<xxx>; XSRF-TOKEN=<xxx>'
```

It doesn't matter if there is an object to delete (should send 200) or it does not (404) - the response that client gets is 403. I tried in console and in Postman.

In case it matters here are logs from the container:
Not found:

```
2023-04-25T00:10:10.269Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-25T00:10:10.269Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-25T00:10:10.270Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-25T00:10:10.270Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-25T00:10:10.271Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DELETE "/api/todo/2c08f95b", parameters={}
2023-04-25T00:10:10.271Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-25T00:10:10.275Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select t1_0.id,t1_0.completed,t1_0.title from to_do t1_0 where t1_0.id=?
2023-04-25T00:10:10.285Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolved [com.ditidev.demospring.exception.EntityNotFoundException]
2023-04-25T00:10:10.285Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-04-25T00:10:10.286Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-04-25T00:10:10.287Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
```

200:

```
2023-04-25T00:10:38.548Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-25T00:10:38.549Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-25T00:10:38.550Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-25T00:10:38.551Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-25T00:10:38.551Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DELETE "/api/todo/40ae6186", parameters={}
2023-04-25T00:10:38.551Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-25T00:10:38.555Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select t1_0.id,t1_0.completed,t1_0.title from to_do t1_0 where t1_0.id=?
2023-04-25T00:10:38.562Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from to_do where id=?
2023-04-25T00:10:38.576Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-04-25T00:10:38.578Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-04-25T00:10:38.579Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
```

The biggest concern I have is with the repeating *BasicErrorController#error* messages, so I tried to follow then, but didn't get anywhere. Also I was running remote debugging and in fact sometimes it did send correct response to the client, but I wasn't able to pinpoint what makes the change. There is only one thing that usually happens at the same time - Java errors:

```
2023-04-25T00:21:57.403Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
```

and

```
2023-04-25T00:21:57.404Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed.
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:144) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
```

**EDIT 26.04.2023**
I did more debugging and only after removing completely security config I realised that some of my requests throw something unexpected, but hidden at a first glance (response status is unchanged, so I didn't look in logs assuming all is fine).

```
2023-04-26T00:01:38.289Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DELETE "/api/todo/7e999648-3cbc-49d0-b698-2a7a2733a644", parameters={}
2023-04-26T00:01:38.290Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ditidev.demospring.controller.ToDoController#deleteById(String)
2023-04-26T00:01:38.296Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select t1_0.id,t1_0.completed,t1_0.title from to_do t1_0 where t1_0.id=?
2023-04-26T00:01:38.383Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from to_do where id=?
2023-04-26T00:01:38.494Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-04-26T00:01:38.495Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for DELETE "/error", parameters={}
2023-04-26T00:01:38.497Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-04-26T00:01:38.498Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2023-04-26T00:01:38.499Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Wed Apr 26 00:01:38 UTC 2023, status=200, error=OK, message=Succesfully deleted., path=/a (truncated)...]
2023-04-26T00:01:38.500Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 200
```

Now, although without full confidence yet, I can say that most likely 403 was sent by security filters due to this unexpected part about ERROR dispatch. Without security enabled response status simply remains and I must have missed it before.
Now, one more important thing - this only happens with DELETE requests (no matter what outcome).

**Another EDIT**
Looks like one of the reasons (and there were two) was adding 'reason' for the status

```
@ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.OK, reason="Succesfully deleted.")
```

Why would that be a problem? Originally I made my delete methods not return anything which resulted in lack of feedback, so I added 'reason' to have something. Now I set object to be returned (or String) and it does not throw any unexpected errors, but I still have to see what would happen with void.

Onto the second reason - it is the custom exception, but here I can't seem to understant what's wrong, because it literally looks like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {}
```

There is now way this is problematic, but it must be since this exception is also used by GET method when failing to find object. Another idea that I have is that maybe custom response requires ResponseBody annotation, but why would it not be needed when response is an object from DB. Here are my methods to review:

```
@GetMapping
public List<ToDo> findAll(){
    return toDoService.findAll();
}

@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ToDo create(@RequestBody ToDo toDo){
    return toDoService.save(toDo);
}

@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.OK, reason="Succesfully deleted.")
public ToDo deleteById(@PathVariable String id){
    return toDoService.deleteById(id);
}
```

PS I still need to verify if fixing what I found is the answer for my initial question, but obviously I need the root reason to be understood too.

Comment: My wild guess is, your 403 error due to missing or incorrect  authorization configuration.  check on authorizeRequests() in websecurity  configuration.

Comment: @VladUlshin I'm not modifying this part at all, so it is default. The only part modified is login success handler, authentication entrypoint (sending 401). Everything else is as present above in the config.

Comment: I added some more information including potential root cause of the problem. I still need to know why is that even a problem

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem and found similar behavior.

Comment: On my tests, I found that without providing ( --header 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==') I get 401, also can't access resource ( using curl ) with a session cookie  after successful authentication (even after removing CSRF protection) IMHO httpBasic() can't handle session and needs Authorization header on each request.   On web based test, if request to resource throw an exception (inside resource method)  I get 403  error without any special handling - that is similar what you have.

Comment: Yes, lack of return token gives 401, which is intended (config will direct you to failureHandler), but once authentication is correct, but any kind of exception happens, you always get 403 as a default error from security. It probably makes some sense - you don't want to say too much about your insides, but from development perspective it's a little problematic.
Anyway, sad part is that now when I know what's the cause I suddenly can find tons of articles talking about 403 in spring, but I couldn't couple of days ago :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a lot of testing I'm certain of the problem now.
It seems 403 is a default error code for every exception which is thrown by the security with CSRF protection. It is most likely default behaviour and maybe even wanted. Such response doesn't contain anything useful - neither real status code, nor reason.
Why did it happen to me for the successful requests? This is a bit tricky, but it seems whenever @ResponseStatus contains "reason" (ignoerd when empty) Spring assumes it's a reason for unwanted behaviour and by default throws an error. And this error is a sign for security to block the response and send 403.

```
 * <p><strong>Warning</strong>: when using this annotation on an exception
 * class, or when setting the {@code reason} attribute of this annotation,
 * the {@code HttpServletResponse.sendError} method will be used.
```

This is not very satisfying (Exception handling, not response status reason) as I probably have to find a way to change this behaviour at least for dev environment as it makes testing a lot easier. I've seen something about AccessDeniedHandler, but I need more reaserch. Still a hint for those who will face similar issue.